# Javascript grid with Kinetic scrolling suitable for Mobile/Tablets

Tags: javascript, grid, scroll

I have been looking for a Javascript based datagrid to use for Mobile websites/applications with no luck. I have tried jqGrid, which seemed to work fine except for the lack of kinetic scrolling. I know jqGrid does now have a (beta) mobile version, but unfortunately is is built upon jquery mobile, and I am using a different framework (which spat the dummy when I included the jqquery mobile scripts)

So, my question is, does anyone know of a Javascript grid that does support Kinetic scrolling (or know how to apply this to an existing grid)?

Would need this to not be reliant on any other UI framework (such as jquery mobile - nothing against this, I just happen to be using another one and it didn't seem to want to coexist)

If it supported knockout type of binding then even better!!! (I know this is expecting too much).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any info!

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic scrolling is a built-in feature in Webix DataTable http://webix.com/widget/datatable.
The grid control processes all touch events without a hitch. It runs scrolling touch events especially well http://webix.com/blog/datatable-1000-columns-and-more/.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I just wanted to leave a note here as well if someone ends up here using the search.

You should check out , which is a top-notch Javascript grid component, and has kinetic scrolling on touch devices. It’s part of Vaadin Components: http://www.vaadin.com/components